# when i am using SpringMVC+hibernate + tomcat

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I am using SpringMVC+hibernate+tomcat to create a webapp.when i start tomcat.There is no error or warning.The website is ok。But when i commit some data,the chrome is keeping pending.there is no error in the tomcat log.I am learning to use SpringMVC.
Spring-config.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.gujiaqi" use-default-filters="false">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Service" />
    <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
</context:component-scan>
```

spring-controller.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.gujiaqi" use-default-filters="false">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
    <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Service" />
</context:component-scan>
<!-- ... -->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/page/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

spring-hibernate.xml:

```
<!-- 配置数据源 -->
<bean id="dataSource"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/springmvc" />
    <property name="username" value="soho" />
    <property name="password" value="123456" />
</bean>

<!--  配置hibernate SessionFactory-->
<bean id="sessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hiberante.format_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <!-- 这里为SessionFactory配置了实体bean的自动扫描 -->
        <list>
            <value>com.gujiaqi.bean</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- 事务管理器 -->
<bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
</bean>
<!--启动spring注解功能-->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="serviceOperation" expression="execution(* com.gujiaqi.service.impl.*.*(..))" />
    <aop:advisor pointcut-ref="serviceOperation" advice-ref="txAdvice" />
</aop:config>
<!-- 事务代理类 -->


<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="update*" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
        <tx:method name="save*" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
        <tx:method name="add*" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
        <tx:method name="create*" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
        <tx:method name="do*" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
        <tx:method name="del*" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
        <tx:method name="remove*" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
        <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" />
        <tx:method name="query*" read-only="true" />
        <tx:method name="find*" read-only="true" />
        <tx:method name="*"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
```

are there any wrong in profiles?

Maybe my english is poor and the question is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does the service method look like that is hanging? Try to do this in order to further debug it:

- put a breakpoint on the service layer method that is called, to see if it get's called
- let it hang, pause the debugger and then look at the stack of each thread on the debugger view, see what the threads are doing. most will be inactive, but one will be running the call to your service. The stack will tell you why it's hanging
- Look at the database what is happening, how many sessions are opened, are they blocked etc., use [My SQL workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)
- increase the logging levels of spring and hibernate to DEBUG

If still stuck, can you post your further conclusions and the service method code itself?

Comment: it is transaction's problem.I will fix it.